# Partition positioning and listing in disk management

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, disk-management

I'm trying to extend my C partition without re-installing OS and for that purpose I need some space after C: partition in disk manager.So I want to know is there a way I can bring C before D and un-allocated space.In short, I want to manage partitions alphabetically and need advice for the matter

[image]

Comment: You would have to delete the E drive to accomplish what you want.  You cannot event the C drive with unallocated space that comes before it.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can bring C at start so it would look more neat and organized and any other option apart from formatting E.

Comment: Would require you to image each partition by itself but you don't want to reinstall the OS so that automatically throws that opinion out of the door

Comment: Backup the **D:** and **C:** logical drives.  Then try using a partition editor such as GParted to (1) delete the D: partition, (2) move the C: partition to the left (to the beginning of the drive), (3) resize the C: partition (extending it to the right), (4) recreate a smaller partition for D:.  These steps cannot be combined. Steps 3 & 4 can also be done in Windows instead of GParted.

Comment: @sawdust step 2 isn't clear...The un-allocated space would be before C so how I can bring C to the left?

Comment: *"The un-allocated space would be before C ..."* -- That's exactly what you need in order to move the partition.  The deleted D partition and the existing small unallocated region should coalesce into a single unallocated region of about 247 GB, that would span from the beginning of the drive to the start of the existing C partition.  After you perform #2, verify success by trying to boot from the drive.